# How to call a ListViewBuilder with JSON Data

Tags: list, flutter, http, listview, dart

Hello everyone i want to fetch Data from my Database and build a ListView out of it.
The first part works perfectly but i struggle by drying the second part.
This is the Code where i want to fetch the data with.
And at //HERE// i want to call a function whit a Listviewbuilder in it which creates a ListTile with the JSON data for any time he is called.

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> senddata() async {
  final response = await http.post(
      "https://www.bumsbirne.com", body: {
    "status": "0",
  });

  var datauser = json.decode(response.body);
  var number = datauser['Number'];
  print(number);
  var i = 0;

  while (number > i) {
    i++;
    Future<Map<String, dynamic>> lol() async {
      final response =
      await http.post("https://www.bumsbirne.com", body: {
        "status": 1.toString(),
        "nummer": i.toString(),
      });
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

       //HERE//

      print(data);
      return data;
    }
    lol();
  }

  return datauser;
}
```

Thanks for any answer